# Mysql: "\." doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I was trying to upload an `.sql` file to mysql console with `\.` but it throwed me:

```
mysql> \.  /home/krest/s.sql;
ERROR: 
Failed to open file '/home/krest/s.sql;', error: 2
```

However, "source" command works properly!

What I am doing wrong?

I am running console through ubuntu 14.04 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Look closer to the error message, everything you need to know is there:

```
Failed to open file '/home/krest/s.sql;', error: 2
```

Error 2 is "No such file or directory". You can use the `perror` command line tool to find out the message from an error code returned by MySQL.

Did you figure out what's wrong? The semicolon after the file name is not supposed to be there. MySQL thinks it is part of the file name and this is why it cannot find the file.

As a side note, it seems that some of the short commands work if the ending semicolon is preceded by a space and do not work without the space (`\u`, for example, works this way). Others take everything until the end of line as parameter (and fail with an error because of the ending semicolon).